# Gandi.net DNS Records setup for Mailgun Domain Verification and DNS

Tags: dns, subdomain, records

I need to know the specific DNS Records that I have to input into Gandi.net DNS Records, so that I can use mailgun with my virtual server.

The current DNS Records are as follows:

```
@ 86400 IN MX 10 mxa.mailgun.org.
@ 86400 IN MX 10 mxb.mailgun.org.
@ 10800 IN SPF "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
email.mg 10800 IN CNAME mailgun.org.
mailo._domainkey 10800 IN TXT "k=rsa...IDAQAB"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks mostly right, but one or two things could be changed.  I'm using the same services and also on a VM and this works for me:

mg 10800 IN CNAME mailgun.org.
@ 10800 IN SPF "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
mailo._domainkey.mg 10800 IN TXT "k=rsa; p=MIG...QAB"
email.mg 10800 IN CNAME mailgun.org.
@ 10800 IN MX 10 mxa.mailgun.org.
@ 10800 IN MX 10 mxb.mailgun.org.

Also, in the end I didn't see any need to create a subdomain even though they recommend it.  So if you really don't need one either just truncate the ".mg" from the mailo & email entries as well as the mg CNAME record and it'll work like a charm.